# Loop to load incremental string names but with different prefix and suffix

Tags: c++, string, opencv, c++11, counter

I am trying to load at each loop increment a new image from a sequence into a variable with openCV for C++.

I am running into a problem because only part of the name changes in the middle but the prefix and suffix don't.

Here is the file name : 9987-1-0001-357.033.png

Next one would be : 9987-1-0002-357.066.png

As one can see, the number of the frame changes and the timestamp.

I am trying to find a way to automatically load the next image into a variable using C++.

Is there a way to abstract the timestamp to only increment a counter on the number of the frame (9987-1-000*.png ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Sure, just have a template string and a replacement and then use a formatting function.

Comment: Thanks @SombreroChicken! I am not sure on how to do that, would you have an example please ?

Comment: I would iterate though your directory looking for files that match your pattern (C++ regexs will be helpful here, as will the C++ filesystem library). Then sort the file names based on the frame number, then load. I don't see how you can do this without accessing the file system if your timestamps are unpredictable.

Comment: pseudo code: `current_filename =  "9987-1-0001-357.033.png"; current_number = atoi(current_filename.split("-")[2]); next_number = current_number + 1; next_filename_prefix = "9987-1-" + itoa(next_number); next_filename = find_file_that_starts_with(next_filename);`

Comment: @NadavS I haven't found a function that lets me implement the find_file_that_starts_with, any idea on a library that could help doing that ?

Comment: To find all files in a directory - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator. To find if a string starts with another string - `strncmp` from https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp .