# Find the next image with OpenCV c++

Tags: c++, string, image, opencv, c++11

I have a sequence of images which are collected and named this way :

1st image: "9199-1-**001**-200.033"

2nd image: "9199-1-**002**-200.066"

305-th image: "9199-1-**305**-210.066"

In bold is the number of the image and after is the timestamp and they are the only two parts changing for each image.

Is there a way for me have a loop which increases the index of the image and loads the next filename regardless of the timestamp in c++ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are using C++11, this would be OS specific.  [How do I get a list of files in a directory in C++?](//stackoverflow.com/q/306533)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop to load incremental string names but with different prefix and suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987689/loop-to-load-incremental-string-names-but-with-different-prefix-and-suffix)